# How loud would everyone in the world's breathing be, when gathered together?

Tags: earth, noise

If everybody in the world gathered in one place, how loud would everybody's combined breathing be? If you could, please say how loud it would be relative to any familiar noise (for example, a foghorn).

Or, you could describe this problem as, "how loud would would a 2-d array of 7 billion, 10dB speakers be"?

Comment: Before or after the suffocation begins?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but it would most likely be before.

Comment: Xkcd discusses some issues with getting everyone in one place https://what-if.xkcd.com/8/

Comment: Please would you show your own attempt to answer this question.

Comment: @sammygerbil I am working on it but it was a joke.

Comment: In my opinion, this question is very clearly about physics and it is clearly not a homework. It is a naive question of a curious man.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a physics question.

Comment: I think this is a potentially interesting physics question. It could be worded better. It would be better phrased as "how loud would would a 2d array of 7 billion, 10dB speakers be?"

Comment: This isn't really a homework question. I've seen similar questions that haven't been put on hold, and it's interesting, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breathing ~ 10dB  assume this is 1m away.

Use calculator on this site http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-distance.htm to estimate dB at a distance.

If you are 3m away, their breathing would be inaudible (below 1dB). This suggests that you would only hear people roughly within 3m of you. If people were spaced in a grid with 1 meter spacing then you would have on the order of 9 people within 3m of you. Nine people breathing is not loud (personal experience). While to really treat this we could  integrate the effect of everyone but since the intensity falls off as $r^{-2}$ we know most of the noise you'll hear will be local to you. This suggests it will remain quiet. This is consistent with experience where a group of people can be pretty quiet if they try.

Answer (score -2):

A single human breathing is about 10 decibels, so estimating that the world's population is 7.5 billion, it would be about 75 billion decibels, or 750,000,000 times louder than a garbage truck getting your trash.

Comment: This could only be true if all 7.5 billion could occupy the same space. Which from personal experience on the subway is not possible.

Comment: @LasersMatter :-) You are right, but I suspect, in this case we can idealize the "gathered in one place" substring of the title as if they would be in a sound-insulated room.

Comment: @peterh I hadn't thought of interpreting the question that way. That is very interesting because if the ceiling was low and was highly reflective then the sound intensity would fall off as $r^{-1}$ instead of as $r^{-2}$. I suppose we should request clarification on the question. A lower ceiling would add to the oxygen problems.